# How to get values using CASE statements in SELECT clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I have table `Table1` that contains a column: `Column1`

| Column1 |
| --- |
| AAA Machine-1 |
| BBB Machine-2 |
| CCC Machine-3 |

I need a output as below based on values of `Column1`

| Process | Machine |
| --- | --- |
| First Process | Machine-1 |
| Second Process | Machine-2 |
| Third Process | Machine-3 |

How can I achieve these values using `CASE` statement? or, is there other way to get the results?

Comment: Use character functions  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-06062705-1EC8-44ED-89B8-0F0573B74EA2

Answer (score 1):

This is one option:

```
SQL> with table1 (column1) as
  2    (select 'AAA Machine-1' from dual union all
  3     select 'BBB Machine-2' from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6    'Process-' || substr(column1, 1, 1) as process,
  7    substr(column1, instr(column1, ' ') + 1) as machine
  8  from table1;

PROCESS   MACHINE
--------- -------------
Process-A Machine-1
Process-B Machine-2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

in oracle:

```
SELECT 
  case SUBSTR(COLUMN1,INSTR(column1,'Machine-',1) + LENGTH('Machine-'),LENGTH(COLUMN1))
    when '1' then 'First Process'
    when '2' then 'Second Process'
    else 'Third Process'
 end as Process,
  SUBSTR(COLUMN1, 5, LENGTH(COLUMN1)) AS Machine
FROM TABLE1
```

in sql

```
    SELECT 
      case SUBSTRING(COLUMN1,CHARINDEX(column1,'Machine-',1) + LEN('Machine-'),LEN(COLUMN1))
        when '1' then 'First Process'
        when '2' then 'Second Process'
        else 'Third Process'
     end as Process,
      SUBSTRING(COLUMN1, 5, LEN(COLUMN1)) AS Machine
    FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: Thanks, but, I have edited the question a while ago which require a different way

Comment: I changed the query according to your change.

Comment: Thanks again! but, there is not any common pattern to match the Process Column. Suppose there may be a value like 'GP COIL Machine-1' and I need to map with Process name as 'Galvanizing'. That means, I need to check if COLUMN1 contains a string like 'GP COIL'

Comment: I set the pattern to Machine-1. If it changes, you no longer have a fixed pattern to do this.

Comment: @LucasEthen you should use SUBSTR(COLUMN1, INSTR(column1,'Machine-',1)  AS Machine , you have a fixed pattern right now, i.e, SUBSTR(COLUMN1, 5, LENGTH(COLUMN1)) AS Machine

Answer (score 0):

You can use date format element suffix for ordinal numbers along with `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function in order to return `Process` column and `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` regular expression function to extract `Machine` column through splitting by space character such as

```
SELECT INITCAP(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY column1) || '-01-01',
                               'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                       'YYYYSPth')) || ' Process' AS "Process",
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(column1, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) AS "Machine"
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f6ae12b46389339a5c931e31c901abf6)</kbd>